# printing out random string from an array

Tags: c++

I need little help with the code. I am trying to print out a random string from the array but have no idea how. Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

        string name[2] = {"Nao","Shilla"};
        string behaviour[4] = {"recognise","detect","avoid","replace"};
        string position[4] = {"above","below","left","right"};
        string pronoun[3] = {"I","you","they"};
        string object[4] = {"car","person","dog","diamond"};
        string texture[3] ={"smooth","dimpled","rough"};

        cout <<name[0] << " " <<behaviour[0]<< " "<<texture[0] << " " <<object[0] <<endl;
}
```

Comment: You could use the `rand()` function for a start. There is no indication of anything "random" here, otherwise.

Comment: I was looking at the rand() but didn't know how to implement inside the code

Comment: A couple of good ways: generate a random number and use it as the index for the array. Probably what @ArnavBorborah is hinting at. Another oldie-but-goodie [is to `std::shuffle` the array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) and pick the first element.

Comment: For each of the string arrays, use `array_name[rand() % size_of_array]`. So for `name`, use `name[rand() % 2]`. Make sure to include `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: In place of `rand` [may I suggest `std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)? Usage example at the bottom of the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a random string from an array, you can use the [`rand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) function, which generates a random number, in the following way:

```
array_name[rand() % array_size] // Overflow is not handled here
```

Thus, for the array `name`, you could use:

```
name[rand() % 2] // Overflow is not handled here
```

The same goes for the rest of the arrays (Make sure you seed the random number generator with `srand(time(nullptr));` and to include `<cstdlib>`). Another approach would be to use [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) on each of the arrays (Using pointer addition for the iterators), and taking the first element of each of the shuffled arrays.

On a side note, if you want a better random number generator, you can use [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use `rand()` which generates pseudo-random number from 0 to RAND_MAX. To archieve random number from given interval you should use modulo operator `%`.
For example: `output = rand() % (max-min) + min` generates numbers from `min` to `max` (exclusively). Also remember to initialize it on beginning of your code: `srand(time(NULL))`

More elegant solution would be to use `<random>` features such as `std::uniform_int_distribution`